# How to check URL format

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to check whether the url format is `@Url.Content("~/Dashboard/Index?studentId=")`. If it is, we have to set `@Url.Content("~/Dashboard/Index")`, if not `window.location.href`. How to do it?

```
var currentUrl = (@Url.Content("~/Dashboard/Index?studentId=")) ? (@Url.Content("~/Dashboard/Index")) :  window.location.href;
if (currentUrl.indexOf('#') > -1) {
    currentUrl = currentUrl.replace('#', '');
}
else {
    currentUrl += '#';
}
window.location.href = currentUrl;
```

Comment: You  can make Regex pattern for url and can match url with this to ensure url format is correct. Isn't it?

Comment: Can you give a bit more of explanation, why are you expecing a URL to be in the format "@....", that's Razor and should be parsed at the server level. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I too have questions, it looks like you are just trying to strip off the query string, is that the case?

Comment: Also searching for hash `#` but that's not part of the razor url. Don't mix server code and javascript!

Comment: The thing is I'm getting the window.location.href value and I want to check whether it has the same studentId which I have

Comment: you can use search method to check if the value has your specified studentId, if it doesn't the method would return -1